# Additional space in p-type column swallowed by other cell

Tags: tables, spacing

I want to add extra vertical space after table rows on a row per row basis. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{5cm}}
  Here...             & ... it works.                  \\[2ex]
  And...              & ... here \newline it does too! \\[2ex]
  But\newline here... & ... it does not.               \\[2ex]
  Some more text.     & Even more text.
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

In the first two lines, everything is fine. In the third row, however, the multi-line left column swallows the extra space. I want this line to look like if one added `\vspace{2ex}` right after `here...`.

I thought the optional argument of `\\` would add vertical space after the complete row, not only after the last cell. How can I add space below a row without knowing which of the columns is the highest, and without affecting the other rows?

Comment: You should use `\addlineskip[2ex]` (or without the optional parameter) of the package `booktabs` here. This fixes your problem (and we all do like `booktabs` tables here :-)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using `booktabs`:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{5cm}}
        Here...             & ... it works.                  \\\addlinespace[2ex]
        And...              & ... here \newline it does too! \\\addlinespace[2ex]
        But\newline here... & ... it does not.               \\\addlinespace[2ex]
        Some more text.     & Even more text.
    \end{tabular}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I need! I almost always use the `booktabs` package anyway, but I wasn't aware of this. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `\noalign{\vspace{2ex}}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{5cm}}
  Here...             & ... it works.                  \\[2ex]
  And...              & ... here \newline it does too! \\[2ex]
  But\newline here... & ... it does not.               \\\noalign{\vspace{2ex}}
  Some more text.     & Even more text.
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this interesting solution.  Could you please tell us, why it is working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `arraystretch` command to alter the spacing between rows. In your case:

```
\documentclass{article}

 \begin{document}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
  \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{5cm}}
    Here...             & ... it works.                  \\
    And...              & ... here \newline it does too! \\
    But\newline here... & ... it does not.               \\
    Some more text.     & Even more text.
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This will yield the following (@LaRiFaRi `booktabs` solution is added for reference):
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but my example was probably not the best. I don't necessarily want to add the same space after each column, but rather choose on a row per row basis (as is possible with `\addlinespace[]`).

Comment: I see. But why don't you just change the `\\[2ex]` to a larger value (say `\\[5ex]`) for the row that is causing the problem?

Comment: That's what I did so far, but it requires a lot of fiddling around to get the right value, since the height of the "tallest" cell is unknown.