# Vertical spacing works only for the first line

Tags: tables

Someone stumbled on a strange problem and asked my for help.  She had a `tabular` environment and wanted to increase the vertical spacing between the table lines.  I advised her to use `\\[1.2ex]` if she desired so.  To my absolut astonishment, this did only work for the first line, every other `\\[1.2ex]`  was ignored without any warning or error message.

I was able to boil this down to loading the `array` package.

This is an MWE, which will produce the requested results

```latex
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}             % 1) German Orthography
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                % 2) Output font encoding
% \usepackage{array}                      % 3) More Control over table layouts
% \newcolumntype{H}{>{\footnotesize}c}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{} llp{10cm} @{}}
  % \multicolumn{1}{@{} H}{Nummer} & \multicolumn{1}{H}{Name} & \multicolumn{1}{H@{}}{Inhalt}\\
  Nr. & Name & Inhalt \\
  1 & Einleitung & Kontext, Problem und Aufgabenstellung, Ziele\\[2ex]
  2 & Theorie & Stand der Technik, Möglichkeiten der Versuchsumsetzung, vorangehende Versuche, Vor- und Nachteile, Absehbare Probleme\\[2ex]
  3 & Versuchsaufbau & Konkrete Umsetzung, Material und Aufbau, Randbedingungen, beteiligte Personen\\[2ex]
  4 & Durchführung & Durchführen des Versuches und Sammeln von Messdaten, Dokumentation, Fehlerquellen\\[2ex]
  5 & Auswertung & Analyse der Messdaten, Mathematische Berechnungen (Konfidenzintervall, Fehlerfortpflanzung, \dots), Was bedeuten Ergebnisse für Versuch\\[2ex]
  6 & Interpretation & Wie können Ergebnisse zukünftige Forschung beeinflussen, Wurde Ziel erreicht?\\[2ex]
  7 & Fazit & Zusammenfassung aller vorherigen Kapitel, abschließende Bewertung\\[2ex]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

(To make the point visually more clear, the above MWE uses `\\[2ex]`  instead of `\\[1.2ex]`.  The size of the additional vertical space has no influence on this problem.)

The result looks like this:
[image: Table, where all lines have additional vertical space]

Now, slightly change the above example by loading the package `array`.

```latex
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}             % 1) German Orthography
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                % 2) Output font encoding
\usepackage{array}                      % 3) More Control over table layouts
% \newcolumntype{H}{>{\footnotesize}c}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{} llp{10cm} @{}}
  % \multicolumn{1}{@{} H}{Nummer} & \multicolumn{1}{H}{Name} & \multicolumn{1}{H@{}}{Inhalt}\\
  Nr. & Name & Inhalt \\
  1 & Einleitung & Kontext, Problem und Aufgabenstellung, Ziele\\[2ex]
  2 & Theorie & Stand der Technik, Möglichkeiten der Versuchsumsetzung, vorangehende Versuche, Vor- und Nachteile, Absehbare Probleme\\[2ex]
  3 & Versuchsaufbau & Konkrete Umsetzung, Material und Aufbau, Randbedingungen, beteiligte Personen\\[2ex]
  4 & Durchführung & Durchführen des Versuches und Sammeln von Messdaten, Dokumentation, Fehlerquellen\\[2ex]
  5 & Auswertung & Analyse der Messdaten, Mathematische Berechnungen (Konfidenzintervall, Fehlerfortpflanzung, \dots), Was bedeuten Ergebnisse für Versuch\\[2ex]
  6 & Interpretation & Wie können Ergebnisse zukünftige Forschung beeinflussen, Wurde Ziel erreicht?\\[2ex]
  7 & Fazit & Zusammenfassung aller vorherigen Kapitel, abschließende Bewertung\\[2ex]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And the result will change dramatically:
[image: Faulty table, where only the first line show additional vertical space.]

As you can see, only the first `\\[2ex]` was executed, while every other `\\[2ex]` was silently ignored.  The log file does not give any warning or error.

This example was produced on TeXLive  of end 2021, using array.sty in version v2.5c

> \ProvidesPackage{array}[2020/10/01 v2.5c Tabular extension package (FMi)]
> Using `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex` makes no difference at all.

(Removing packages `babel` and `fontenc` will change the outcome in the expected way: problems with Umlauts.  Trying this with an english text, without package `babel` and `fontenc` still has the same problem.  I haven't found any hint in the `array` manual either.)

Comment: Both of your examples don't compile properly since the `booktabs` is missing. Since you already seem to use said package, why not replace `\\[2ex]` with `\\ \addlinespace`?

Comment: Probably related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232331/134144

Comment: You can also use something  like `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}` or  `\extrarowheight2ex`  to avoid mess with the low format of every table.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you for your comment.  I edited the MWEs and removed the remains of the booktabs package.

Comment: @Fran thank you for your comment.  But I think, loading the `array` package shouldn't do such harm.  Shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why `array` package do such harm, however for adding more vertical spaces around cells contents is better to use dedicated packages for adding vertical space above/below cells contents. For example the `makecell` package, which define macro `\makegapedcells`:

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}             % 1) German Orthography
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                % 2) Output font encoding
\usepackage{makecell}                   % 3) More Control over table layouts
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} llp{10cm} @{}}
Nr. & Name 
        & Inhalt        \\           
  1 & Einleitung 
        & Kontext, Problem und Aufgabenstellung, Ziele  \\
  2 & Theorie 
        & Stand der Technik, Möglichkeiten der Versuchsumsetzung, vorangehende Versuche, Vor- und Nachteile, Absehbare Probleme   \\
  3 & Versuchsaufbau 
        & Konkrete Umsetzung, Material und Aufbau, Randbedingungen, beteiligte Personen \\
  4 & Durchführung 
        & Durchführen des Versuches und Sammeln von Messdaten, Dokumentation, Fehlerquellen \\
  5 & Auswertung 
        & Analyse der Messdaten, Mathematische Berechnungen (Konfidenzintervall, Fehlerfortpflanzung, \dots), Was bedeuten Ergebnisse für Versuch    \\
  6 & Interpretation 
        & Wie können Ergebnisse zukünftige Forschung beeinflussen, Wurde Ziel erreicht? \\
  7 & Fazit 
        & Zusammenfassung aller vorherigen Kapitel, abschließende Bewertung
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or the `cellspace` package, which define macros

```
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{...}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{...}
```

For using them in selected columns you need extend column specification with option `S` (default, but you can rename it according to table specific) or `C`, if in table is used `S` columns defined in the `siunitx` package.

In your case the MWE can be:

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}             % 1) German Orthography
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                % 2) Output font encoding
\usepackage{cellspace}        % better, than {} aren't necessary
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} Sl S l S{p{10cm}} @{}}
% table body is the same as before
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But you may liked `tabularray` package, which has defined (among others) command `rowsep` by which you can simple change spaces between table rows. In example below is for third column used `X` column type which cause that table width is equal to `\textwidth` (similarly if the `tabularx` table would be used):

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tblr}{
               colspec = {@{} l l X[j] @{}},
              row{2-Z} = {rowsep=5pt}, % add space between table body rows
                 }
% table body is the same as before
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Result is similar as before:

[image]